# Ideas for a complicated menu

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have a slightly complicated menu to code from PSD document and integrate into Wordpress.

This is how it looks:

[image: http://i54.tinypic.com/m8h93m.png]

The result of my work is this:

http://slavisaperisic.com/FlexE/meni_setap.html

Now, when I write function  `wp_list_pages();`  I get the default markup:

```
<ul>
<li class="page_item"><a href=""></a></li>
<li class="page_item"><a href=""></a></li>
<li class="page_item"><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

But the markup I created (that gives me the appropriately styled dynamic menu) looks like this:

```
<div id="menu">

                    <div id="menu-left"></div>
                    <div id="main-menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active first">
                                <div class="left_li"></div>
                                <a href="#" class="active">Exploring</a>
                                <div class="right_li"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="second">
                                <div class="left_li"></div>
                                <a href="#">Using</a>
                                <div class="right_li"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="third">
                                <div class="left_li"></div>
                                <a href="#">Downloading</a>
                                <div class="right_li"></div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu-right"></div>

                </div>
```

I styled it so that it follows the length of the word in the menu item. Obviously, I can't use the `wp_list_pages()` function because the structure it gives me is different than the one I need.

Do you have some ideas? Maybe point me to somewhere where I can learn to code it differently or explain it to me?

Comment: The example you posted seems to be working.  What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: @Sparky672: OP wants to know how to style the first snippet to function like the second, because he is stuck with the first markup even though the second is functional.

Comment: BTW tbh I'd stick with the images for the menu item text.

Comment: Yeah, well, images instead of text would simplify things a lot, but it doesn't really make menu that dynamic...

Comment: @Tomalak:  I agree, but that's not entirely clear by reading the question.  Also, what is the specific reason he cannot simply edit the Wordpress files so he's not stuck with anything?

Comment: @Sparky672: Seemed clear to me. And hacking up Wordpress internals is clearly inferior to styling templates to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @IWalkedAway: Does it need to be dynamic? How often will you add pages?

Comment: I don't really know if it HAS to be dynamic, I just wanted to know if there is a plausible solution. I will now be doing maintenance or anything after I complete coding and WP integration. I guess I'll leave it hardcoded then...

Comment: @Tomalak:  I'm not endorsing the hacking of anything... when I said Wordpress "files", I consider the templates as part of that.  I'm only asking these questions to improve the quality of this question and narrow down what this OP is looking to do... like, _"does it need to be dynamic?"_ and _"have you yet tried to edit the Wordpress files (templates)?"_

Comment: @Sparky672: My understanding is that [`wp_list_pages()` is a core Wordpress function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages), so changing its output is hacking with internals.

Comment: @IWalkedAway: I completely understand the desire to make it dynamic and auto-extensible. In this case, though, you may -- repeat, _may_ -- be better off leaving it hardcoded with your pretty images. :) At the very least you shouldn't rule out this option.

Comment: @Tomalak:  Then you misunderstood me, because by editing a template, including his custom menu code and not using the `wp_list_pages`, will also change output.  Yet the OP does not even mention templates in his question... hence my asking for clarification.

Comment: I thought so. 
Thank you both for your comments, I'll try to explain my boss those same things :)

Comment: @Sparky672: He wants to use `wp_list_pages`. That is what this question is about. And [that `wp_list_pages` outputs a list is not themeable](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L807).

Comment: @Tomalak:  Yes, I get it... that's why I up-voted your comment about sticking with images.  I have no argument with you... IMHO, I just think the question could have been written a little better... like mentioning up front if there was a critical need for it to be dynamically updatable.  I also think my own initial comment should have been written better.

Comment: @Sparky672: Both may be true. :)

Comment: If you don't mind it degrading to simpler styles in older browsers, it would be possible to style the former mark-up example to look very similar to this in CSS3 using the :after pseudo-element, border-radius and the CSS triangle technique (http://jonrohan.me/guide/css/creating-triangles-in-css/) I started to write it for you, but it would take me more time than I have to spare. I'm convinced it would be possible though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on for size. I've tested it in Chrome and Firefox.

Mark-up:

```
<ul>
  <li class="page_item active"><a>Exploring</a></li>
  <li class="page_item"><a>Using</a></li>
  <li class="page_item"><a>Downloading</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul, li { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
ul {
  float: left;
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: 2px solid #DDD;
  height: 46px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
}
ul:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -45px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #DDD transparent;
  border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0) rgba(255,255,255,0) #DDD rgba(255,255,255,0);
  border-width: 0 45px 45px 0;
}
li {
  float: left;
  height: 26px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
li:after {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  right: -40px;
  top: 4px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #EEE transparent;
  border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0) rgba(255,255,255,0) #EEE rgba(255,255,255,0);
  border-width: 0 42px 42px 0;
}
li a {cursor: pointer;}
li a, li.active a:hover {color: #999;}
li a:hover, li.active a {color: white;}
li.active {background-color: lightblue;}
li.active:after {border-bottom-color: lightblue;}
```

You can see it in action here:
http://static.robinwinslow.co.uk/menustyling.html

I can't test in IE on this Ubuntu machine, but I think:

- IE9 should be fine
- IE8 should show triangles but not border radii
- IE7 won't show triangles or border radii

Is that a good enough solution?

Comment: Not really a great solution for me in this case but you showed some excellent skill that I can obtain and use in the future. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use wp_nav_menu to create custom menus. Details can be http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Using this you can create markup similar to:

```
    <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item">
        <a href="http://sewsoon.co.uk/">
            <strong>Home</strong>
            <span>Start Over</span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

However, you may want to look into using pseudo elements before: and after: to keep the markup more semantic. Depending upon if you're including javascript libraries or not you could use http://selectivizr.com/ to patch ie support.

Comment: Also, you can override WordPress's nav menu by creating `Walker_Nav_Menu` descendant class and overriding menu behavior.